# How can I make vertices on a cylinder create a circle?

Tags: modeling, mesh

How can I make vertices on a cylinder create a *circle* (like in this tutorial https://youtu.be/cHbOCSkqmo8?t=2m43s) ?

[image]

Comment: Honestly, I won't do that. I'd rather ask somewhere else. 1. The video describes perfectly well what I want to do. No word could describe it better. 2. This is definitely NOT off-topic. 3. If someone does not understand, well, I suggest to not answer at all. 4. Downvoting this is just so lame. Get a life...

Comment: You were actually right about that it wasn't offtopic. As it was then it should've been closed as "unclear what are you asking". If the question is not clear the questioner is advised/asked to add clarification and that's *totally* fine. The question most likely was downvoted because of one reasons for that "the question doesn't show any research, is unclear". So read the rules of the site. Words *can* describe what you want; if you can't add 2 images - before and after. Now your quesiton is clearer.

Comment: @marcus I like the first idea of your friendly comment.

Comment: @marcus asking a question with just a link to a video is "just so lame." Really you cant be bothered to write your question in a way so that it is answerable without going somewhere else? You don't have to get all in a huff over the DVs. This site do not allow link only questions or answers. The post must be self standing. Just reading your question it *was* unclear. Thus why it got closed (and DVed).

Answer (score 5):

You may use ***To Sphere*** operation (as @Dontwalk pointed), but ***Loop Tool's Circle*** creates much better result.
[image]

Activate the ***Loop Tools*** add on in *User Preferences* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>). Apply the transformations to the object (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>-->*Rot&Scale*). Select the edges on a *cylinder* you want to transform to a *circle* and snap the cursor to it (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>). Press <kbd>W</kbd>-->*LoopTools*-->*Circle*. Finally uncheck the *Flatten* checkbox in a *Circle* panel of a *Tool Shelf* (<kbd>T</kbd>).
[image]

You may then extrude the circle inwards as was shown in the tutorial.
[image]